# How to save connection settings in TightVNC Viewer?

Tags: vnc

I use TightVNC Viewer version 1.4.0 and want to save 75% scale and Full-screen mode settings. When I set them, close connection and then open it again, settings are default again.

How to save it permanently? Is it possible to save a password?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Windows XP:

1. When you have the settings as you like them, hold down the Ctrl key, and press Esc.

   Right-click on the TightVNC in your task bar, and select "Save connection info as..." (it will ask if you want to save the password).

   Use the saved .vnc file instead of the TightVNC executable to launch your remote session

For Windows 7 (Right clicking in the Task Manager doesn't display the correct menu):

1. Get the settings the way you want them.

   If that includes full screen, hold down Ctrl, Alt, and Shift, and press the F key.

   Click on the program icon above the toolbar and select "Save session to a .vnc file..." (it will ask if you want to save the password)

   If you want full screen, open the saved file and change `fullscreen=0` to `fullscreen=1`.

   Use the saved .vnc file instead of the TightVNC executable to launch your remote session.

Comment: Thanks for this information. When click this .VNC file an error occurs: 
1) "Argument error" / "Invalid VNC server specified.". The
2) "TightVNC info" / "Failed to get serer address (-m_config). Did you type the host name correctly?"

My .VNC file begins like this:

[connection]
host=192.168.1.103
port=5900

IP address is correct. What can be wrong here?

Comment: But loading this config file when app is opened  works good, so it is already very good.

Comment: Are [connection], host=192.168.1.103, and port=5900 all on different lines? (Okay, so probably the superuser comments just don't allow putting them on different lines). Did you edit the file in Notepad or some simple text editor? I don't know how TightVNC behaves if there are weird line endings. Also, is version 1.4.0 a beta? All I see on their site is 1.3.10 (stable) and 2.0 Beta. Maybe 1.4.0 has a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TightVNC 2.x, on Windows it is not straight forward like you would expect. 
You should save connection info to .vnc file, and you cannot just Open with... tvnviewer.exe

The full procedure is that you should Copy shortcut of your existing VNC Viewer, rename it to your connection name and right click it, click Properties and inside Target editbox put parameter called `optionsfile`. The final Target should look like this:

`"C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnviewer.exe" -optionsfile="C:\fullpath\savedconnection.vnc"`

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnviewer.exe" -optionsfile=FILENAME.vnc
```

Comment: What do you do with this?

Comment: But this means that you have your `vnc` file already saved which is what OP is actually asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I am a TightVnc newbie but am 'familiar' with 'programming' techniques (well, just about keeping my head above the waterline). This question is a bit old but it had me stumped for a while. Here's what I did to get a copy of the TnvViewer 'OptionsFile':

> 1. Open/Load TightVnc Viewer on my Windows 10 PC; ie connect to the other PC.
> 2. On the toolbar of the TightVnc viewer window > click the 'save' icon ("Save session to .vnc file".
> 3. This opens a Windows Explorer 'save' window to my Windows PC; navigate to my chosen folder, create a filename, and click 'Save'.
> 4. I now have a 'standard/basic' options file to play with.

Apologies, as I cannot confirm what all the options do; I was just pleased to get the file.
As long as the Windows Explorer 'Open With' link connects the options file with TnvViewer, double clicking the options file puts me straight into TnvViewer on my nominated PC.
Hope this helps other Newbies.

Answer (score 0):

In my version of TightVNC 1.2.9, the target must look like this (`/config`  instead of `-optionsfile=` in Arunas' answer):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VNC\vncviewer_T129.exe" /config "C:\Users\...\vnc\mysettings.vnc"
```

Comment: Please [edit] this so it makes sense by itself.  It’s OK to copy part of [Arunas Bartisius’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/116853/150988#881283) as long as you give credit. Also, please identify your version of TightVNC.

Comment: I did not copy anything from somebody elses answer.

Comment: I didn’t say that you did copy anybody’s answer. My point is that, all by itself, your answer doesn’t make much sense. I suggested that you improve it to say something like, “As [Arunas Bartisius says](https://superuser.com/q/116853/150988#881283), the procedure is to make a copy of your VNC Viewer shortcut, open Properties, and change the Target field. But, for TightVNC 1.2.9, the target must look like this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\VNC\vncviewer_T129.exe" /config "C:\Users\...\vnc\mysettings.vnc"` (using `/config ` instead of `-optionsfile=` in Arunas' answer).”

Answer (score 0):

The configuration options you mentioned are options of the vncviewer program, so, the answer depends on what kind of viewer you use. There are already several answers applicable in case you run vncviewer on windows machine.

In case your client machine is linux and you use vncviewer installed together with tigervnc package, the viewer configuration file located at `~/.vnc/default.tigervnc`.

You have to create the file manually, example of file contents (first string is magic, must be exactly like like this):

```
TigerVNC Configuration file Version 1.0

MenuKey=F12
FullScreen=1
RemoteResize=0
```

Available options are described in `man`:

```
man vncviewer
```

Answer (score 0):

On current TightVNC version: start a session, then click the diskette on the button bar. You'll be asked to save the password there. If you do and then double click on the saved session, the connection will be opened immediately without asking for password. Unfortunately, TightVNC is too stupid to offer profiles as Putty does.